# Encounter missing key in state dict: 0.0.weight", "0.1.weight", "0.1.bias", "0.1.running_mean"

Tags: python, fast-ai

I am trying to develop a phone classifier model for my university project. I've already trained my model and I encountered a problem when I am trying to deploy the model by executing python app/server.py serve. I read a post(https://forums.fast.ai/t/unexpected-key-s-in-state-dict-model-opt/39745)
and I suspect the problem is due to different fast.ai version running between my anaconda and Google Colab.

Therefore,I've tried to check the version of fastai in my computer by using pip list fastai, conda list fastai and import fastai; fastai.**version** in my Google colab(I used Google Colab to develop my model) but the results are the same(fastai version = 1.0.59). I even tried to update my fastai version in Google Colab but in vain. Here is the exception code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/server.py", line 37, in <module>
    learn = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))[0]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "app/server.py", line 32, in setup_learner
    learn.load(model_file_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 279, in load
    get_model(self.model).load_state_dict(state, strict=strict)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 845, in load_state_dict
    self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Sequential:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "0.0.weight", "0.1.weight", "0.1.bias", "0.1.running_mean", "0.1.running_var", "0.4.0.conv1.weight", "0.4.0.bn1.weight", "0.4.0.bn1.bias", "0.4.0.bn1.running_mean", "0.4.0.bn1.running_var", "0.4.0.conv2.weight", "0.4.0.bn2.weight", "0.4.0.bn2.bias", "0.4.0.bn2.running_mean", "0.4.0.bn2.running_var", "0.4.1.conv1.weight", "0.4.1.bn1.weight", "0.4.1.bn1.bias", "0.4.1.bn1.running_mean", "0.4.1.bn1.running_var", "0.4.1.conv2.weight", "0.4.1.bn2.weight", "0.4.1.bn2.bias", "0.4.1.bn2.running_mean", "0.4.1.bn2.running_var", "0.4.2.conv1.weight", "0.4.2.bn1.weight", "0.4.2.bn1.bias", "0.4.2.bn1.running_mean", "0.4.2.bn1.running_var", "0.4.2.conv2.weight", "0.4.2.bn2.weight", "0.4.2.bn2.bias", "0.4.2.bn2.running_mean", "0.4.2.bn2.running_var", "0.5.0.conv1.weight", "0.5.0.bn1.weight", "0.5.0.bn1.bias", "0.5.0.bn1.running_mean", "0.5.0.bn1.running_var", "0.5.0.conv2.weight", "0.5.0.bn2.weight", "0.5.0.bn2.bias", "0.5.0.bn2.running_mean", "0.5.0.bn2.running_var", "0.5.0.downsample.0.weight", "0.5.0.downsample.1.weight", "0.5.0.downsample.1.bias", "0.5.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "0.5.0.downsample.1.running_var", "0.5.1.conv1.weight", "0.5.1.bn1.weight", "0.5.1.bn1.bias", "0.5.1.bn1.running_mean", "0.5.1.bn1.running_var", "0.5.1.conv2.weight", "0.5.1.bn2.weight", "0.5.1.bn2.bias", "0.5.1.bn2.running_mean", "0.5.1.bn2.running_var", "0.5.2.conv1.weight", "0.5.2.bn1.weight", "0.5.2.bn1.bias", "0.5.2.bn1.running_mean", "0.5.2.bn1.running_var", "0.5.2.conv2.weight", "0.5.2.bn2.weight", "0.5.2.bn2.bias", "0.5.2.bn2.running_mean", "0.5.2.bn2.running_var", "0.5.3.conv1.weight", "0.5.3.bn1.weight", "0.5.3.bn1.bias", "0.5.3.bn1.running_mean", "0.5.3.bn1.running_var", "0.5.3.conv2.weight", "0.5.3.bn2.weight", "0.5.3.bn2.bias", "0.5.3.bn2.running_mean", "0.5.3.bn2.running_var", "0.6.0.conv1.weight", "0.6.0.bn1.weight", "0.6.0.bn1.bias", "0.6.0.bn1.running_mean", "0.6.0.bn1.running_var", "0.6.0.conv2.weight", "0.6.0.bn2.weight", "0.6.0.bn2.bias", "0.6.0.bn2.running_mean", "0.6.0.bn2.running_var", "0.6.0.downsample.0.weight", "0.6.0.downsample.1.weight", "0.6.0.downsample.1.bias", "0.6.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "0.6.0.downsample.1.running_var", "0.6.1.conv1.weight", "0.6.1.bn1.weight", "0.6.1.bn1.bias", "0.6.1.bn1.running_mean", "0.6.1.bn1.running_var", "0.6.1.conv2.weight", "0.6.1.bn2.weight", "0.6.1.bn2.bias", "0.6.1.bn2.running_mean", "0.6.1.bn2.running_var", "0.6.2.conv1.weight", "0.6.2.bn1.weight", "0.6.2.bn1.bias", "0.6.2.bn1.running_mean", "0.6.2.bn1.running_var", "0.6.2.conv2.weight", "0.6.2.bn2.weight", "0.6.2.bn2.bias", "0.6.2.bn2.running_mean", "0.6.2.bn2.running_var", "0.6.3.conv1.weight", "0.6.3.bn1.weight", "0.6.3.bn1.bias", "0.6.3.bn1.running_mean", "0.6.3.bn1.running_var", "0.6.3.conv2.weight", "0.6.3.bn2.weight", "0.6.3.bn2.bias", "0.6.3.bn2.running_mean", "0.6.3.bn2.running_var", "0.6.4.conv1.weight", "0.6.4.bn1.weight", "0.6.4.bn1.bias", "0.6.4.bn1.running_mean", "0.6.4.bn1.running_var", "0.6.4.conv2.weight", "0.6.4.bn2.weight", "0.6.4.bn2.bias", "0.6.4.bn2.running_mean", "0.6.4.bn2.running_var", "0.6.5.conv1.weight", "0.6.5.bn1.weight", "0.6.5.bn1.bias", "0.6.5.bn1.running_mean", "0.6.5.bn1.running_var", "0.6.5.conv2.weight", "0.6.5.bn2.weight", "0.6.5.bn2.bias", "0.6.5.bn2.running_mean", "0.6.5.bn2.running_var", "0.7.0.conv1.weight", "0.7.0.bn1.weight", "0.7.0.bn1.bias", "0.7.0.bn1.running_mean", "0.7.0.bn1.running_var", "0.7.0.conv2.weight", "0.7.0.bn2.weight", "0.7.0.bn2.bias", "0.7.0.bn2.running_mean", "0.7.0.bn2.running_var", "0.7.0.downsample.0.weight", "0.7.0.downsample.1.weight", "0.7.0.downsample.1.bias", "0.7.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "0.7.0.downsample.1.running_var", "0.7.1.conv1.weight", "0.7.1.bn1.weight", "0.7.1.bn1.bias", "0.7.1.bn1.running_mean", "0.7.1.bn1.running_var", "0.7.1.conv2.weight", "0.7.1.bn2.weight", "0.7.1.bn2.bias", "0.7.1.bn2.running_mean", "0.7.1.bn2.running_var", "0.7.2.conv1.weight", "0.7.2.bn1.weight", "0.7.2.bn1.bias", "0.7.2.bn1.running_mean", "0.7.2.bn1.running_var", "0.7.2.conv2.weight", "0.7.2.bn2.weight", "0.7.2.bn2.bias", "0.7.2.bn2.running_mean", "0.7.2.bn2.running_var", "1.2.weight", "1.2.bias", "1.2.running_mean", "1.2.running_var", "1.4.weight", "1.4.bias", "1.6.weight", "1.6.bias", "1.6.running_mean", "1.6.running_var", "1.8.weight", "1.8.bias".
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "opt_func", "loss_func", "metrics", "true_wd", "bn_wd", "wd", "train_bn", "model_dir", "callback_fns", "cb_state", "model", "data", "cls".
```

My fastai version is same as fastai in Google colab but I still get the same problem.I expect my model to be deployed on my local server.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mrfabulous1, I understood the reason that caused this, Thus, I share his response to someone who wants to deploy their model locally in the future.

In my experience of creating at least 20 apps between Google Colab and Anaconda on my desktop, it is not possible for the app to work unless your Anaconda environment matches the Colab environment 100%.

In practice this means that when you do !pip list on Colab where you trained your model. All the files library versions used in the requirements.txt file in the app, must be changed to match versions you received when you did !pip list on Colab.

If you try and run a model/app on your desktop in an Anaconda environment the app will fail, unless all the file versions numbers in your anaconda environment match the Colab versions.

Sometimes point 2 even fails as libraries can be security patched or have minor changes that haven’t been announced yet and don’t have a version number associated with them.

So it means you need to create a new anaconda environment each time you train a model on Google Colab and any library versions are different to your current Anaconda environment.

If you change your current Anaconda environment library versions, then all your existing apps created with that environment may/will break.

In summary create new environment every time library/libraries on Colab differ from libraries on Anaconda.

Cheers mrfabulous1
ps. I now use Docker to overcome this issue.